# How to make a List of Lists based off a Json file

Tags: java, arrays, json, list, nested-lists

I have a JSON file I'm iterating over, using gson, I loop through the file and store them all in lists. The problem I am facing is when I iterate over the nested list. Instead of making the output have multiple lists inside the outer list like this `[[], [], []]` it is just adding everything into the first inner list like this`[[adds everything here]]` I'm not sure why it is doing this, I have tried multiple things already nut cant get it to work properly

this is my JSON file
I am trying to make a list of lists in which each contain a P, I, and D

```
{
    "pos":[
       {
         "x": 1.0,
         "y": 1.0,
         "theta": 1.0,
         "drive":[{
            "p": 0.1,
            "i": 0.1,
            "d": 0.1
         }]
       },
       {
         "x": 2.0,
         "y": 2.0,
         "theta": 2.0,
         "drive":[{
            "p": 0.2,
            "i": 0.2,
            "d": 0.2
         }]
          
       },
       {
         "x": 3.0,
         "y": 3.0,
         "theta": 3.0,
         "drive":[{
            "p": 0.3,
            "i": 0.3,
            "d": 0.3
         }]
          
       }
    ]
 }
```

this is how I loop through it

```
        String json = readFileAsString(file);
        System.out.println(json);

        JsonManager manager = new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<JsonManager>() {}.getType());

        List<PosData> posList = manager.getPositions();
        List<Double> xList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Double> yList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Double> thetaList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Double> drivePID = new ArrayList<>();
        List<List<Double>> driveLists = new ArrayList<List<Double>>();

        
        for (PosData pos : posList) {
            xList.add(pos.getX());
            yList.add(pos.getY());
            thetaList.add(pos.getTheta());

            for(PidData pid : pos.getDrive()){
                drivePID.add(pid.getP());
                drivePID.add(pid.getI());
                drivePID.add(pid.getD());
                break;
            }

            driveLists.add(drivePID);
            
            System.out.println(drivePID);
            System.out.println(driveLists);
        }
```

this is the final output I would like to have

```
[[0.1, 0.1, 0.1], [0.2, 0.2, 0.2], [0.3, 0.3, 0.3]]
```

but this is what it does when I print out the loop

```
[[0.1, 0.1, 0.1]]
[[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2], [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]]
[[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3], [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3], [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3]]
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Why a list instead of a proper object with properties `p`, `i`, `d`?

Comment: well for my use case these are like coordinate and data that would be used for a robots autonomous routine so ill be needing to loop the lists once again to transfer them into robot positions

Comment: `for(PidData pid : pos.getDrive()){List<Double> drivePID = new ArrayList<>();
                drivePID.add(pid.getP());
                drivePID.add(pid.getI());
                drivePID.add(pid.getD());driveLists.add(drivePID);
                break;
            }` should work it seems.

Comment: but it doesn't it give me this output ```[[0.1, 0.1, 0.1]]
[[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2], [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]]
[[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3], [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3], [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3]]```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize `drivePID` list on each loop:

```
   for (PosData pos : posList) {
        xList.add(pos.getX());
        yList.add(pos.getY());
        thetaList.add(pos.getTheta());

        for (PidData pid : pos.getDrive()) {
          List<Double> drivePID = new ArrayList<>();
          drivePID.add(pid.getP());
          drivePID.add(pid.getI());
          drivePID.add(pid.getD());
          driveLists.add(drivePID);
          break;
        }

        System.out.println(driveLists);
      }
```

Output:

```
[[0.1, 0.1, 0.1]]
[[0.1, 0.1, 0.1], [0.2, 0.2, 0.2]]
[[0.1, 0.1, 0.1], [0.2, 0.2, 0.2], [0.3, 0.3, 0.3]]
```

Comment: thanks i didnt think something that simple can cause my problem